# How to update multiple variable with one value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to update tree variables with the same value. 
I need to set new date for variables. Can I do it with only one query?

I use query:

```
 db.getCollection('my.data').update( {}, { $set : { "Time1" : new ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true); 
 db.getCollection('my.data').update( {}, { $set : { "Time2" : new ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true); 
 db.getCollection('my.data').update( {}, { $set : { "Time3" : new ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true);
```

The question is how to simplify it? I just need to get such result:

```
"Time1" : ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z")
"Time2" : ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") 
"Time3" : ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb - How can I updated multiple elements of a nested object using $set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617915/mongodb-how-can-i-updated-multiple-elements-of-a-nested-object-using-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('my.data').update( {}, { $set : { "Time1" : new ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") , "Time2" : new ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") , "Time3" : new ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(in PHP): -

```
for($i = 1; $i<4; $i++)
    db.getCollection('my.data').update( {}, { $set : { "'Time.'$i" : new ISODate("2016-01-14T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true);
```

Run this loop how many times you want to update...